# Lua variable as a function call

Tags: function, properties, lua

I need to define some variables in lua which when accessed result in a call of C++ function:

```
Lua:
var rootname = root.name; // 'root' acts as a call to c++ function defined below

C++:
class Node
{
    std::string name;
}

Node * root()
{
   return MyNodeGraph->GetRoot();
}
```

Is that possible in Lua?

Comment: Yes. Check the lua api.

Comment: When accessing `root`, you are accessing the `_G` table for the index `root`. What you want to do is already implementable in vanilla Lua.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like that. That's acutally one of the most common use cases of Lua. Although the proper Lua syntax would be `local a = prop()` if you want a to be 5.

Read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/
and https://www.lua.org/pil/24.html
https://www.lua.org/pil/25.html
https://www.lua.org/pil/26.html

Comment: right, but in your case I have to add a brackets but I want to avoid that

Comment: If you don't want straight way, you can go all around. Run your script in separate environment that has metatable set. You can catch reading uninitialized globals then, and translate that into calls to native functions.

Comment: I've added some more details so you could clearer  understand what I need, please take a look

Comment: You can set same metatable on 'root' table instead of global environment table.

Answer (score 0):

Setting metatable of _G might not be part of the "Lua best practices" but here you go:

```
setmetatable(_G, {
  __index = function(t, k)
    if k == "root" then
      return root_function() -- Call your C function here.
    end
    return rawget(t, k)
  end
})

-- This function is just for a quick test. Call C function instead of this.
function root_function()
  print("in root_function")
  return { name = "hello" }
end
--

-- Test
rootname = root.name
print(rootname) -- Prints "hello"
```